# how to concat each element in array by another single string value in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to concatenate multiple element in array with another string using swift 5:
ex:

```
MyArray = ["Bat","Foot","Basket"]
MyString = "Ball"

output = ["BatBall","FootBall","BasketBall"]
```

Or

```
output = ["BallBat","BallFoot","BallBasket"]
```

How should I do this? Please help.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to do this in a complete simple way, you can do this:

```
var myArray = ["Bat","Foot","Basket"]
var myString = "Ball"

for i in myArray.indices {
    myArray[i] = "\(myString)\(myArray[i])"
    print(myArray[i])
}
```

This way you can add any kind of data, every where you want.

Comment: Yikes, there a lot of bad practices in this small piece of code. 1) local variables should be `lowerCamelCase`. 2) You're mutating in-place rather than making a new `output` variable. 3) `0...x - 1` should never be used. It crashes for empty arrays. Use `0..<x` instead. 4) You shouldn't use `count` to create indices, because it doesn't work for slices. Use `for i in array.indices`. I wrote a whole bit on this: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md

Comment: I copy the code from the question, really didn't think of the best practices, sorry
@Alexander i'm gonna edit it right now.
and about array.indices, I really didn't know about that, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

you can achieve this by map functionality :

```
var myArray = ["Bat","Foot","Basket"]

var output = myArray.map { $0 + "ball" }

print(output) // ["Batball", "Football", "Basketball"]
```